# AngularJS dynamic partial in $templateCache is being stripped

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Either my code is haunted or I made a mistake:

I have a json feed:

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "identifier": "header",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "identifier": "onebyone",
          "html": "<h1>API</h1>"
        },
        {
          "identifier": "onebyone",
          "html": "<h1>API</h1>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "identifier": "content",
      "blocks": []
    },
    {
      "identifier": "footer",
      "blocks": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I make a call in my AngularJS controller and I sort the sections and try to concat the html blocks, so:

```
cmsApp.controller('cmsPageCtrl', function($scope, $http, $templateCache, $sce) {

    $http.get("/api.php/api/page/home")
        .success(
            function(response) {
                $scope.sections = [];

                response.sections.forEach(function(el, idx, arr) {
                    var id = el.identifier;

                    $scope.sections[id] = el;
                    //$scope.sections[id].template = "<h1>HOI</h1>";
                    $scope.sections[id].template = 'header.html';

                    var template = "TEST";

                    el.blocks.forEach(function(el, idx, arr) {

                        var partial = el.html;
                        template = template + partial;
                    });

                    template = template + "<div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>";
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(template);

                    $scope.sections[id].template = 'header.html';

                    $templateCache.put('header.html', $sce.trustAsHtml(template));
                    console.log(template);

                });
            }
        );
});
```

Now one would expect that the following output of this:

```
<body ng-app="cmsApp" ng-controller="cmsPageCtrl">
    <ng-include src="sections.header.template"></ng-include>
</body>
```

To be:
`TEST<h1>API</h1><h1>API</h1><div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>`

Result is:
`<span class="ng-scope">TEST</span><div class="ng-scope"><b>b</b>TEST1</div>`

The console output is:

```
cms.ctrl.js (line 33)    TEST<h1>API</h1><h1>API</h1><div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>
cms.ctrl.js (line 34)    TEST<h1>API</h1><h1>API</h1><div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>
cms.ctrl.js (line 39)    content
cms.ctrl.js (line 33)    TEST<div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>
cms.ctrl.js (line 34)    TEST<div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>
cms.ctrl.js (line 39)    footer
cms.ctrl.js (line 33)    TEST<div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>
cms.ctrl.js (line 34)    TEST<div><b>b</b>TEST1</div>
cms.ctrl.js (line 39)
```

What is responsible for stripping the HTML in the header section output?

Answer (score 1):

Angular does that by default to protect against injection. If you really want to do it, you need to include the [ng-sanitize](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize) plugin, then add the module to you app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

and then bind your html content using the ng-bind-html directive.

```
ng-bind-html="myHTML"
```

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Add to GPicazo, you are updating the html cache in all loops with deferents values for the same key. This mind that the value that persist is the last one.

Comment: @RaúlMartín - Not sure what you are talking about. Was  your comment mean for the original question?

Comment: In the original code don't make sense use this templateCache.put('header.html', $sce.trustAsHtml(template)); inside in a loop

Comment: Good point. But I think your comment belongs on the question, not on the suggested answer.

Comment: @RaúlMartín You are completely right. Damn those friday afternoons... I was just blind... Of course it doesn't make sense. Kudos to you, bro.